# App visible to all languages in play store?

Tags: android, translation

I'm wondering if my app is visible to all languages if you select all countries when deploying.

My app is currently only in english, although it is ready to translate in the future with all the string resources. I deployed it to all countries when publishing it to app store, but I'm wondering if someone that has their phone in russia for example.. will they still see the english listing? Or does the play store automatically hide listings that aren't in the phones language?

I'm wondering how much of a rush I'm in to translate.. if they don't see the app then I won't rush to translate it.. but if they can see it, and skip or delete the app after installing because it's in another language, I will try to get it done faster.

Thanks!

Comment: Play store doesn't translate your app. I think it's a paid service to get your app translated. So at present your app will be in English for all the users across the world.

Comment: Yes I know it doesn't translate it, I was just wondering if it would still show as english if their phone is in a different language. Thanks!